# laravel mix not working and my localhost:8000 not work

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I create a laravel project with vue js. At first I have created laravel new project and then command npm install. and then command npm run dev
When I command in windows powershell: npm run watch
then whole things are compiled and then When I change somehing in app.js in laravel project and save this file. There is no notice about laravel mix. Besides When I write in my web browser: localhost:8000
I can't see my project. I can see a error message: This site can’t be reached
How can I solve this problem.

Comment: I think you are missing details about your environment

Comment: Do you actually have a server running? try php artisan serve

Comment: Tnx bro @ege.  I forgot to run the command: php artisan serve. it's so funny. hahaha